# How to use intsafe.h functions with MSVC?

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I am trying to compile a simple program using the [intsafe.h](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/intsafe/) header with MSVC:

```c
#include <intsafe.h>

int main(void) {
  int result;
  return IntAdd(10, 10, &result);
}
```

When trying to compile this program I get an error from the linker

```
/opt/msvc/bin/x86/cl test.c 
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.37.32825 for x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

test.c
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.37.32825.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/out:test.exe 
test.obj 
test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _IntAdd referenced in function _main
test.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

However, I can't find where the IntAdd symbol exists. I used dumpbin against all of the .lib files that came with the MSVC distribution and none of them showed this symbol. The documentation for [IntAdd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/intsafe/nf-intsafe-intadd) also makes no mention of any library (in contrast to other functions like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wow64apiset/nf-wow64apiset-wow64disablewow64fsredirection#requirements)), so I am not sure what to tell the linker

Comment: Agree that this is bizarre, the definitions in intsafe.h are inline.

Comment: `ENABLE_INTSAFE_SIGNED_FUNCTIONS` must be defined, otherwise `IntAdd` not visible at all

Comment: Note that when C23 eventually goes live, there will be a `stdckdint.h` for this very purpose. Then you won't need these fishy MS libs any longer, given that you'll use a standard C compiler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IntAdd` is defined in conditional block

```
#if defined(ENABLE_INTSAFE_SIGNED_FUNCTIONS)
...
#endif
```

if you use *c++* - you get

```
error C3861: 'IntAdd': identifier not found
```

but with *c* compiler let use not declared `IntAdd`
but because `_IntAdd` (this mean that you use `x86` and `__cdecl`) really not defined in any obj or lib you got linker error

If you want to use `IntAdd` do next:

```
#define ENABLE_INTSAFE_SIGNED_FUNCTIONS
#include <intsafe.h>
```

also read comment from *insafe.h*

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// signed operations
//
// Strongly consider using unsigned numbers.
//
// Signed numbers are often used where unsigned numbers should be used.
// For example file sizes and array indices should always be unsigned.
// (File sizes should be 64bit integers; array indices should be size_t.)
// Subtracting a larger positive signed number from a smaller positive
// signed number with IntSub will succeed, producing a negative number,
// that then must not be used as an array index (but can occasionally be
// used as a pointer index.) Similarly for adding a larger magnitude
// negative number to a smaller magnitude positive number.
//
// intsafe.h does not protect you from such errors. It tells you if your
// integer operations overflowed, not if you are doing the right thing
// with your non-overflowed integers.
//
// Likewise you can overflow a buffer with a non-overflowed unsigned index.
//
```